# Laravel: how to use scoped function

Tags: laravel, scope

I have a question regarding the use of a scope in Laravel.

I have a tweet-model tweet.php in which I have defined a scope:

```
    public function scopeWithLikes(Builder $query)
{
    $query->leftJoinSub(
        'select tweet_id, sum(liked) likes, sum(!liked) dislikes from likes group by tweet_id',
        'likes',
        'likes.tweet_id',
        'tweets.id'
    );
}
```

The underlying tweet-table is:

```
        Schema::create('tweets', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->foreignId('user_id');
        $table->string('body');
        $table->string('image')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('retweet_id')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();


        $table->foreign('retweet_id')->references('id')->on('tweets');
    });
```

The underlying likes-table is:

```
        Schema::create('likes', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreignId('tweet_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->boolean('liked');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->unique(['user_id', 'tweet_id']);
    });
```

The scope adds "likes" and "dislikes" to the tweet.

Somewhere in my code I have an instance of a Tweet and I want to grab the tweet it refers to in the retweet_id:

```
$tweet->find($tweet->retweet_id)
```

This works fine, except that I get an instance without the likes and dislikes. How can I apply the WithLikes scope in such a way that teh new tweet-instance includes eh likes and silikes?

Kind regards,

HUbert

Comment: The instance is already fetched from the database it is an `object` - you can't run a `select` query on it. You either load as relationship with a new method - or change the query that gives result of the existing instance.

Comment: You are right. I misunderstood the concept. I read the documentation again and now I understand. Thnx.